# How to Apply The Central Limit Theorem For Sums with Multiplication Instead (I Have Partial Solution)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

Suppose I have a list of numbers $x_1, x_2, x_3,...,x_n$, and suppose I pick $t$ elements (with repeats allowed) from that list, and multiply those numbers together. What is the probability that the multiplication is less than $1$?

For example, if my list was $[0.3, 1.4]$ and I wanted to multiply $3$ elements from this list (with repeats), the possible results would be

$\\0.3*0.3*0.3\\0.3*0.3*1.4\\0.3*1.4*0.3\\0.3*1.4*1.4\\1.4*0.3*0.3\\1.4*0.3*1.4\\1.4*1.4*0.3\\1.4*1.4*1.4$

And the probability of picking a term less than $1$ would be $7/8$ since the only term greater than $1$ is the last term.

I am completely okay with finding a way to approximate this, especially since we are assuming that $n$ is sufficiently large and $t$ is sufficiently large for the purposes of this application. I already know that I could use the central limit theorem for sums by taking the logarithm of each $x_i$ (since $log(ab)=log(a)+log(b)$), but my problem is that some of elements in the list are $0$, and I can't take $log(0)$ since that would throw off the mean and the standard deviation of my sums. How can I fix this so that my approximation is at least really close?

I think maybe I could just figure how many zeroes there are and just remove them from the list, and then determine the total possible combinations where a zero could exist in a string of multiplications, and accommodate for that, but it seems kind of annoying...

I'm also willing to try a different strategy.

Comment: Why is removing the zeros annoying? Computationally this is simple and fast, and conceptually this is just total probability. Note that the product is definitely $<1$ is any element with value $0$ is selected. Let $E_0$ be this event. Then your answer is $P(E_0) + (1-P(E_0)) P( \textrm{ product is $<1$} | E_0^c)$. $P(E_0)$ is easy - if some $k$ of the $n$ are $0$, then, since you're sampling with replacement, $P(E_0) = 1 - (1 - k/n)^t$. For the conditional probability, you can take logs and argue via some limiting distribution as you suggested,

Comment: (contd.) or some sort LDP style analysis might be more accurate. The main point is that since you allow repetitions of the same element, you're sampling i.i.d. examples from the empirical distribution induced by the $y_i,$ and this is not too hard to deal with.

Comment: Yeah I figured it might be a little messy, but when you put it the way you did, it looks pretty nice.